# Sourcing bucket and key values from environment variables in CICD

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup a CI/CD for Terraform changes. Our backed is S3 and while `init` I get following errors, since of course none of these values are provided:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  }
}
```

Errors:

```
│ Error: "region": required field is not set
│ Error: "bucket": required field is not set
│ Error: "key": required field is not set
```

Value for `region` as specified [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3)  can be sourced from `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and `AWS_REGION` environment variables.

However, no information is available about how `bucket` and `key` information can be stored as repository secrets or environment variables and can be sourced from there?

I can't specify them in the `backend.tf` files due to some other limitations and they have to be stored as environment variables. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the required values for the `backend` block can be configured using the command line options [1]. Specifically, you should be interested in this part:

> Command-line key/value pairs: Key/value pairs can be specified via the init command line. Note that many shells retain command-line flags in a history file, so this isn't recommended for secrets. To specify a single key/value pair, use the -backend-config="KEY=VALUE" option when running terraform init.

Here is an example from the GitHub actions I used:

```
terraform init -backend-config="bucket=${{ secrets.STATE_BUCKET_NAME }}" \
  -backend-config="key=${{ secrets.STATE_KEY }}" \
  -backend-config="region=${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}" \
  -backend-config="access_key=${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" \
  -backend-config="secret_key=${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" \
  -input=false -no-color
```

I don't have much experience with GitLab CI, but I think you can set those variables as protected and just reference them in the command:

```
terraform init -backend-config="bucket=${STATE_BUCKET_NAME}" \
  -backend-config="key=${STATE_KEY}" \
  -backend-config="region=${AWS_REGION}" \
  -backend-config="access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" \
  -backend-config="secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" \
  -input=false -no-color
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration